# Не могу реализовать логику программы, счетчик всегда обновляется на 0

Tags: ios, swift

Делаю небольшую логику морского боя, реализовал убийство корабля если он занимает 1 клетку, а вот если занимает 2 клетки, то выходит так что счетчик обновляется всегда на 0, и я не убиваю его а просто попадаю, может есть у кого мысли как сделать так чтобы счетчик не обновлялся на 0?
Когда я делаю второй выстрел я обновляю координаты (coordinates) на новые

```
let ship1 = [(x: 9, y: 9)] // координаты первого корабля
let ship2 = [(x: 5, y: 9), (x: 6, y: 9)] // координаты второго корабля

let ships = [ship1, ship2] // объединение кораблей в один массив

var shots = 0 // выстрелы

let coordinates: (x: Int, y: Int) = (5,9) // координаты выстрела

for ship in ships {
    for cell in ship {
        switch coordinates {
        case let (x, y) where x == cell.x && y == cell.y:
            shots += 1
            if shots == ship.count {
                print("Ship \(ship) down!")
            } else {
                print("Ship \(ship) wounded!")
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}

shots == 0 ? print("Missed") : print()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если этот код у вас находится внутри какого-то метода, то можно сделать переменную `shots` глобальной или свойством класса, чтобы она не сбрасывалась при каждом запуске вышеприведенного кода, ну и соответственно потом обнулять ее, если корабль убит, например вот так

```
if shots == ship.count {
    print("Ship \(ship) down!")
    shots = 0
}
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ , нет код не в методе , я только начинаю программировать и до методов и классов еще не дошел , пытаюсь сделать из того что знаю))

Comment: @Виктор успехов!